# jquery get value of specific number inputs in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[what the result looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9ZyY.png)

I'm making a product inventory system; where I can simple change the value with number inputs, hit the checkmark, and be done. But I'm having trouble getting the specific value.

php:

```
<?php
    $get_prod = $con->query("SELECT * FROM products");
    while($get = mysqli_fetch_array($get_prod)){
        echo '
        <div class="prod-inv">
    <div class="prod-inv-top">
        <h1>'.$get['prod_name'].'</h1>
        <h2>'.$get['prod_price'].'</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="prod-inv-body">
        <img class="image-manage" src="'.$get['prod_cover'].'">
        <input id="'.$get['prod_id'].'" type="number" class="num" value="1"/>
        <button id="'.$get['prod_name'].'" class="btn search">&#x2713;</button></a>
     </div>
        </div>';
    }
?>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click(function() {
        var target = this.id;
        var value = $(target).val();;
        alert(value);
    });
</script>
```

I've tried everything from form GET, to href links, now jquery. So far nothing has yelded results.

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1] Firstly, I'm not familiar with PHP, but it seems that closing anchor tag mistakenly presents in the markup:

```
<button id="'.$get['prod_name'].'" class="btn search">&#x2713;</button></a>
```

Or maybe opening anchor tag is missing...

[2] Secondly, in following line:

```
var target = this.id;
```

context "this" is currently clicked button, this code takes clicked button id and then in this line:

```
$(target)
```

you're taking currently clicked button DOM element by it's id, but it is already stored in "this"

[3] when you want to query element by id, you have to prepend it with hash "#":

```
$('#' + target)
```

So, you see the issue, when button is clicked, you take it's id, then find this button on the page again by it's id and then try to take .val() from a button (which actually does not have a value, it is not an input)

---

Suppose, you wanted to achieve following:

button is clicked -> find input near this button -> take value of this input

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var value = $(this).closest('.prod-inv-body').find('input').val();
    console.log(value);
});
```